# Odd lines that aren't entered after the titlepage

Tags: titles

I'm working on my report and after putting a lowercase in the `titlepage` name, somehow weird numbers end up underneath the titlepage on an empty page. The numbers are: `_033303333.27 04453.37 13713.48.` Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this problem. I am not an expert at LaTeX.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

\title{Switching off the genes Llmg{\_}0333, Llmg{\_}0445 and Llmg{\_}1371 by using the >knock-out technique in \textit{Lactococcus lactis} strain MG1363.}
\author{Major report LABlab februari 2014\\
\\
\textit{by}\\
\\
(...)\\
(...)\\
(...)\\
(...)\\
\\
\textit{project ran at}\\
\\
(...)\\
\\
\textit{in cooperation with}\\
\\
(...)\\
\\
\textit{guided by}\\
\\
(...)}
\maketitle

\begin{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi Tim, welcome to the site. Could you fix your sample code so that it gives the error you're getting? At the moment, it doesn't compile because you don't have an `\end{document}`, and the `\maketitle` precedes the `\begin{document}`.

Comment: I think the problem is exactly that `\maketitle` is before `\begin{document}`

Comment: I have tried moving the \maketitle after \begin{document} it moves the problem, since it then turns up on the first page. Understanding you all, You want me too upload the entire document, correct?

Comment: Making it all probably a lot easier: how do you make an underscore? ATM im doing it like {\_} because if I leave the brackets out, all the letters after it become underscore. I want to get like "llmg_0333"

Answer (score 2):

User egreg already stated, that the problem is that `\maketitle` appears before `\begin{document}`, the underscore character can be achieved by typing `\_`.

I introduced the command `\Gennum` which expects the mandatory gennumber as 2nd argument, the first one is optional and defaults to `Llgm`. The underscoring is done automatically.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

\newcommand{\Gennum}[2][Llmg]{%
#1\_#2%
}%

\title{Switching off the genes \Gennum{0333}, \Gennum{0445} and \Gennum{1371} by using the \emph{knock-out} technique in \textit{Lactococcus lactis} strain MG1363.}


\author{Major report LABlab februari 2014\\
\\
\textit{by}\\
\\
(...)\\
(...)\\
(...)\\
(...)\\
\\
\textit{project ran at}\\
\\
(...)\\
\\
\textit{in cooperation with}\\
\\
(...)\\
\\
\textit{guided by}\\
\\
(...)} % End of title

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{I can only guess what comes here}
\end{document}
```

[image]